# How to create a self signed SSL certificate for sslip.io and configure browsers to trust it

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-18.04

The objective is to use secure connections in the development environment using 'magic domain names' provided by services like https://sslip.io. With this setup, it's possible to test services on a local network using URLs like `https://192-168-68-1.sslip.io`. The sslip.io always resolve the domain name to a local IP address, so it only makes sense in the local network, it is not accessible from outside (this is the intended design).

Suppose a webserver running in the local network at 192.168.68.1, port 80. This service can be exposed to the local network via HTTPS using the URL `https://192-168-68-1.sslip.io`. This works great, but the only way to proper configure the SSL is to use a self signed certificate and configure the browser to trust the certificate, otherwise the browser will state that the connection is not secure, preventing web applications to use secure websocket connections to the servers in the same local network.

**The acceptance criteria for answering this question is:**
The Google Chrome should show a valid HTTPS connection in the URL bar when accessing `https://192-168-68-1.sslip.io`.

[image]

The following steps should be part of the answer:

1. How to generate the self signed certificate for the domain name
   `192-168-68-1.sslip.io` using openssl on Ubuntu 18.
2. How to configure Ubuntu 18 and/or Google Chrome to trust the self signed certificate.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've spent hours today trying so many different approaches and nothing has worked yet. I haven't tried https://github.com/cunnie/sslip.io/blob/13b9f3244d3630888e4ea47bfd79dbbb91fa0b5b/docs/wildcard.md yet. It looks super complicated.

Comment: I'll just use https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel instead.